# Which is correct "The party who makes the request " or "The party which makes the request"

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is correct : "The party who makes the request " or "The party which makes the request"

Comment: It depends, in my view on who "the party" is. If it is a sole person, then it would seem more natural to me to use "who". However if "the party" is, for example, the West Midlands County Council, then I would use "which". There are of course a multitude of examples one might think of which are not as clear-cut as these. Then it seems best to me to go with whatever feels right. If you are only dealing with a theoretical point of law, and the party could be anyone, then I suggest "which".

Comment: *The party making…* is clear, simple and ubiquitously correct and I just noticed the big clue in WS2’s *It depends… who "the party" is*. Doesn’t reversing the clue make it obvious the pronoun must fit both singular parties like you and me and corporate bodies like councils and doesn’t that force it to use uncountable *which*? Isn’t that part of the difference between a person and a party?

If the nature of the party does matter then isn’t it clear it must be *The person who…* or *The organisation which makes the request*?

Answer (score 2):

If they sound awkward to you, you might try "The party making the request" instead. I would say it is more natural than either of your choices.

Comment: I wholly agree with Ted. Also, I note that while WS2 has a point, the idea of West Midlands County Council being a party is legal, not linguistic.

Comment: Though I still think using the less awkward the better, the point made by WS2 is well taken - if you are British.  The distinction between groups or teams seen as an entitity or a plurality is a distinction that loses me, but is important grammatically for Brits.  I hadn't run into this issue aside from verb agreement, but here we have a further example. It all seems very optional, and when I discuss the verb agreement with some Brits, they scratch their heads like I'm from another planet.

Comment: Ted, that's a different question despite the overlap but the reason Brits scratch their heads there is that even most of those who care, don't understand.

Comment: @Robbie, I suspect there's more to it than that, but I don't know if this is the place to discuss it at length.  Some things just become anachronistic, when the reasons become obscured/less clear to the user. I am, for example, not so fond of *whom*, and can't use *must needs* in a sentence.

Comment: Ted, I promise there isn't anything more significant to it and my point was that since that's a different question it doesn't belong here.

Why on Earth would you bring up *anachronism* or *obscurity*, let alone *whom* or *must needs*?

Comment: I mention them as anachronisms more of us are familiar with, while you dismiss as irrelevant, something you consider a legal argument, when it is, in fact, a grammatical one, albeit one that is little understood, even by its users. It was also made as a point to cut the argument short.

Comment: thanks and can you acknowledge, all after *The distinction between* belonged to a different question?

Comment: I'm afraid I have to ask you to rephrase that.  Not quite sure what you are getting at.  The original question gave a choice (which I avoided) between two words, "who" and "which". WS2 pointed out that "party" could be referring to a plurality, or a single unit, and hence a different choice of relative pronoun.  I don't see where I have erred in mentioning that that might be more relevant than your dismissal of it as being some legal nuance. Pronoun agreement is important, as is subject/verb agreement (even if it is awkward here).

Comment: Don't you think *the party making* is better because the nature of the party shouldn't matter? Of course the whole thing's really grammatical, and don't you think outside court, it'll come up only in catering? *Party of one for the window table!* Merry Christmas

Comment: I won't be party to this debate any longer!